# adding custom post type "name" to single template

Tags: custom-post-types, single, custom-post-type-archives

i created a custom post type called 30 day boot camp using this code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'rt_custom_post' );
function rt_custom_post() {
  register_post_type( '30-day-boot-camp',
    array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Boot Camps' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Boot Camp' ),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Boot Camp'),
        'add_new_item' => __("Add New Boot Camp"),
        'edit_item' => __("Edit Boot Camp"),
        'new_item' => __("New Boot Camp"),
        'view_item' => __("View Boot Camp"),
        'search_items' => __("Search in Boot Camps"),
        'not_found' =>  __('No Boot Camp'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Boot Camp found in Trash')

      ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
       'menu_icon'   => 'dashicons-calendar-alt',
    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','author'),
    )
  );
}
```

When i am on the archive page (archive-30-day-boot-camp.php)  i can pull the name for the boot camp by this code:

```
<?php if ( is_post_type_archive( '30-day-boot-camp' ) ) : ?>
<h1 class="h-landmark entry-title"><span>
<?php post_type_archive_title(); ?></span></h1>
<?php endif?>
```

and it returns "boot camps"

However when i go to a single entry on my (single-30-day-boot-camp.php)
i can't understand how to return the custom post type name. I want it to return "boot camps"  Not just the post title itself. (which could for instance be "day 1".)

i tried:

```
<?php post_type_archive_title(''); ?>
```

but nothing shows up

i also tried

```
<?php post_type_archive_title('30-day-boot-camp'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're within the loop then the_title() should return the post type's title. post_type_archive_title is specifically for archives.

To get the human readable name of the post type, though, I've not seen anything better than this from the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_object):

```
$obj = get_post_type_object( '30-day-boot-camp' );
echo $obj->labels->singular_name;
```

Comment: i don't want to return the title of the post itself i want to return the title of the post type..  So it would say "boot camps" at the top of the single page and then a little lower i'll return post title.  Sorry if i wasn't clear.

Comment: Ah. I've updated my answer accordingly.